# Bash Script Autoclose Terminal after nohup

Tags: bash, debian

I am trying to make a bash script to improve my skills. The goal is to have the bash script to open another terminal launch the browser and then close it by itself.

I can do everything but make it close on its own.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "type apps you want to launch"
read -r String

if [[ $String =~ "Brave" ]];
        then gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=BashProfile -- nohup bash -c "sleep 1s; brave-browser &" && exit
fi
```

Anyone have a better solution  to what I am trying to do?

I have tried && exit after my command to close it both inside and outside the quotes to see if that closes it. It seems that no command runs after the launch though, which makes sense.

Comment: *"then close it by itself"*. Please specify what you mean by "*it*". Do you mean the script you showed here, or the gnome-terminal you opened?

Comment: Why do you open a terminal if you want to close it immediately after? Opening terminals is probably best left to the user anyway.

Comment: I want the terminal to close that opened the broweser. Some applications run off the terminal so if multiple apps run then multiple terminals are needed. Autoclosing seemed helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exit` in your script only **exits the script which contains the commands** and not the terminal from which it is launched.

I am not sure what you want to kill (the initial terminal or the launched terminal) but try using `kill -9 $$` to kill the parent process. in place of `exit`

(**UNTESTED CODE**)

```bash
#! /bin/bash

echo "type apps you want to launch"
read -r String

if [[ $String =~ "Brave" ]];
        then gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=BashProfile -- nohup bash -c "sleep 1s; brave-browser &" && kill -9 $$
fi
```

Comment: This did not work. Outside the "" you see in the main terminal it was killed but nothing really happens inside the "" it stops the launch entirely.  Was a good idea though